# Is "bevel" used correctly here, to mean a slope of little angle?

Tags: word-usage

I was thinking about writing these lines in a poem, in which I use the word "bevel" to refer to a driveway that is not completely level, but rather on an angle.

> Out beyond the driveway,
>   Where the car sits quietly on a bevel.

I know it is not typical to refer to a driveway as a "bevel", and I must admit I am using this word to achieve a slant rhyme with another word higher up in the poem.

But I wanted to know, does it make sense here? Would you deem it acceptable? Especially given the license typically afforded to the author of a poem?

Here are some dictionary entries that made me hope I could be using the word correctly.

> ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bevel)) 1. An edge that is canted, one that is not a 90 degree angle; a chamfer.
>   *to give a bevel to the edge of a table or a stone slab*
>
> ([Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bevel)) 2a. the angle that one surface or line makes with another when they are not at right angles

But I must admit that neither give me confidence. I would appreciate your opinions!

Comment: @NigelJ I don't think so, because I'm asking about this word in a very specific context (i.e. driveways) whereas that question and its answers do not touch upon this context.

Comment: What has your own research into the word revealed? How many dictionaries even hint at this usage of *bevel* vs how many which do not?

Comment: @NigelJ not really, the correct word here is neither of those given on the question about the building.

Comment: It's ironic you use the phrase *slant rhyme* because *slant* is one word that would probably be appropriate here.

Comment: The word in the question itself is correct - slope. Bevel is inappropriate.

Comment: @WillCrawford Alas, "slant" would not have slant rhyme. I must admit though that it's a moot point now; I am no longer trying to achieve that rhyme.

Comment: I'll add an answer, so at least future visitors have a reference :o)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, thanks for the good tip; I added some dictionary entries that influenced my opinions.

Comment: @NigelJ, +1 for "inappropriate" - couldn't think of the word earlier! Word blindness, I think. Please feel free to suggest other synonyms I missed, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “technical” words for the slope on a driveway are usually:

> **Fall**, which really means the height difference but is usually quoted as a ratio (i.e. the steepness e.g. 1:10 - very very steep - or 1:100 - barely enough to allow proper drainage).
>
> **Slope** (I know, but I have to introduce you to this word, because it's “the <s>sexy</s>obvious one”). The [entry for slope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/slope) in Merriam-Webster's thesaurus even mentions driveways in its example for slope as a transitive verb.
>
> **Slant**, on reflection, sounds wrong in the context of something like a drive or road - the image it conjures up is, well, of a *sideways* slope, or **rake**, similar to a ...
>
> ... **camber**, which usually refers to a *curved* shape of a road - its cross-section, primarily for drainage purposes - or occasionally to the inward tilt that's usually incorporated into a bend in a road. (*Tilt* also implies a sideways slope).
>
> One final term, **grade**, sounds quite old-fashioned to me but appears to be quite commonly used (Stateside, at least) in, I guess you'd call it a “civil engineering” context.

There are plenty of other synonyms listed at the M-W site, and you can follow the links around 'til you find one you like :o)

FWIW, depending on the context and what you were trying to rhyme with, **hill** could work, just by assonance between the -l tails. Long shot, just putting it out there.

Comment: I also missed **ramp**, but that's a quite specific meaning too.